# How can i set any function to repeat after specific amount of time?

Tags: android

public void scheduleAtFixedRate (TimerTask task, long delay, long period). This looks promising but i have no idea how to use it. Any help would be appreciated.It was on android developer site.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this demo helps you:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TimerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay();
      Timer timer = new Timer();

      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, 500, 1000);      
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("working at fixed rate delay");      
   }    
}
```

You need to have a method called "run" in your class, that will be repeately executed.

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_scheduleatfixedrate_delay.htm).

Comment: This is wrong and not relevant to Android. See my answer for an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timer task and schedule it at a fixed rate like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This method is called in a fixed interval
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
```

If you need to interact with the UI in the `TimerTask` you should do it like this:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Interact with UI here
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,
                       long delay,
                       long period)
```

Android doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).

**Parameters**:

- task - task to be scheduled.
- delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
- period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

The task ([`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)) is the code which will be executed forever, every `period` milliseconds. `Delay` is the time (in ms or Date if you want) which the `Timer` should wait until the start of the `TimerTask`.

You should remember Timer will run in a different thread from UI thread, so if you need to update the UI you should use runOnUiThread etc. (See Xaver Kapeller answer)

It could be an example

```
TimerTask tasknew = new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        /* Something here */
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, 500, 1000);
```

I noticed here everyone just posted an example so it's just an extension with an explanation.